# Trying to pass args to a list function

Tags: flutter, list, dart, arguments

```
List<scatterPlot> getChantdatas(double SI, double CV) {
    final List<ScatterPlot> ScatterPlotl = [ScatterPlot(SI, cW)];
    return ScatterPlotl;
}
```

I have this function in another dart file here and I have those two arguments SI and CV. On the Main dart file I want to use the function and pass these two values through it but its giving me an error "Expected to find ';'."

```
double GradientCalculations(double container volume, double C, double H) {
    double size_index = C * H;
    List<ScatterPlot> getChartDataS(size_index, container_volume);
```

I thought it might've been a records language problem so i tried to add that to my 'analysis_options.yaml file but that didn't do anything.

It says i need to add this:
analyzer:
enable-experiment:
- records

Comment: First of all, i suggest you to read about effective dart. please read about how to write code in dart effectively. and for your question give some name to your variable description like so => `List<ScatterPlot> gcd5 = getChartData5(size_index,container_volume);`
i hope this can help, regard

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the function result to any variable. Change this line

```
List<ScatterPlot> getChartData5(size_index,container_volume);
```

To

```
List<ScatterPlot> result = getChartData5(size_index,container_volume);
```